# How do I get the menu to have a scroll

Tags: css, wordpress

My menu box has more content to show but i cannot scroll down to see that content , it just disappears. I have tried doing overflow-y: auto; but does not work.

Here is my code

```
 <div class="nav-cont d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>

    <ul class="menu__box d-flex flex-column ">
        <div class="menu-title-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <p class="menu-title">Most Popular</p>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Batteries</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Engine Oil</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Spark Plugs</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Tyres</a></li>
            <li class="menu-btn-expand"><a class="menu__item" href="#">Show More</a></li>
            <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <div class="menu-title-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <p class="menu-title">Shop Deals</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Top Deals</a></li>
            <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <div class="menu-title-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <p class="menu-title">Shop By</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">By Make</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">By Model</a></li>
            <div class="menu-line-break"></div>
            <div class="menu-title-container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <p class="menu-title">Trustworthy Advice</p>
            </div>

    </ul>
    
  </div>
     
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
/*Hamburger Menu*/
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__btn > span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__btn > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__btn > span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 3rem;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn > span,
.menu__btn > span::before,
.menu__btn > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;

  background-color: #616161;

  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.menu__btn > span::before {
  content: "";
  top: -8px;
}
.menu__btn > span::after {
  content: "";
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;

  left: -100%;

  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;

  list-style: none;

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;

  overflow-y: auto;

  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.menu__box li a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;

  color: #333;

  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;

  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: none;

  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-line-break {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 80%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
}

.menu-btn-expand {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu-title-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I appreciate the help in advance. Thank you. I do not know where the problem is from , I am a bit new to this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the overflow-y: auto; and added overflow: auto; removing the hidden part from either side.

```css
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;

  overflow: auto;

  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: True to give a more specific answer, why you doing this, was does this solve, try to give code that is more to the point.

Comment: Excuse me, how do I?

Comment: @LéoCunha It is still not working , In the snippet it is working but whenever i run it on my code it does not

Comment: The problem is "menu__box" with 100% height and fixed position, you can set a height to get around this problem. - @HZDevs

Comment: Or put in meta__box a calc, height: calc(100% - 100px);

Comment: I edited the answer, the "overflow" has no influence, you can leave it on auto.